# How do bounties work with repcaps?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

I hit my reputation cap earlier today at 215 rep on the day, then I offered a bounty, which dropped my reputation to +165. Now all upvotes I am receiving are not adding reputation, even though I am now under the repcap limit. Is this supposed to work like this, or is it a bug? If it is supposed to work like this, it is highly confusing.

Comment: I think that it is supposed to work like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the cap is based on *total rep gained* from upvotes per day (possibly also suggested edits if your rep were lower) not *net rep gain* per day.

Reducing your reputation by any means does not alter the fact that you have gained the rep cap worth of upvotes.

Some things, like being *awarded* a bounty, or having rep returned due to serial voting reversal will grant you the reputation regardless of hitting the rep cap.

Answer (score 5):

Working as intended.

Bounties, whether you're giving or receiving them, do not count towards the rep cap.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Just the indications of this are a bit confusing.